# Timestamp datatype not supporting in hive, when reading a parquet file

Tags: hive, timestamp, parquet

I have created a partitioned external table in hive that stores parquet format files. I have  timestamp column in that table, when i load data its giving nulls in timestamp column.

create table query

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE abc(
  timestamp1 timestamp,
  tagname string,
  value string,
  quality bigint,
  own string)
PARTITIONED BY (
  etldate string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'adl://refdatalakeprod.azuredatalakestore.net/iconic'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'PARQUET.COMPRESS'='SNAPPY');`

Any suggestions pls?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have specified `timestamp1 String`, this looks like a typo to me? Also note that there are multiple timestamp types in Hive, it might be worth posting the schema of the Parquet files here. You should be able to look it up by using parquet-tools.

Comment: I have also tried using timestamp datatype for timestamp1 field.

Comment: timestamp datatype supported in parquet , you must be doing something wrong while loading the data

Comment: @ShalajShukla ... nothing.. am just creating table as show in the query above and adding a partition to check on that data
alter table abc add IF NOT EXISTS partition(etldate='2017-04-12');

Comment: just check if timestamp value is in proper format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: 2017-04-12 00:15:00.0 its in this format only

Answer (score 0):

Your question is wrong.It's not timestamp type, it is a string type.I think you need to check your data.

Comment: I have tried giving timestamp and finally i gave it as string to check once thats it.

Comment: If you tried with string type and it was still null value, then I think there is something wrong with your primitive data.